# How to create drop down with form in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs

I am trying build drop down with form like [this](https://www.redbus.in/search?fromCityName=Agra&fromCityId=1290&toCityName=Delhi&toCityId=733&onward=08-Oct-2016&opId=0&busType=Any). I used ng-repeat inside li to build a simple dropdown and then placed them inside next to another. the number of columns can also can be dynamic so my approach wont work. How do I proceed to build such a dropdown. Is there any library out there that does this I could not find one.Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Did you inspect that dropdown using Devtools in their site.. you can learn quite a bit..

Comment: I did @RaviTeja but it is not angular. I need a way to do it in angularjs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to do this with Angular, you will need to toggle a dropdown. The following example should be able to get you started: http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/10630/

You will need to compose the columns and associate them with the ng-model.

On Operator field you can do the following:

```
<input ng-model="operator"/>
 <li ng-repeat="result in results | filter:operator</li>
```